# PostgreSQL: update operation synchronization

Tags: postgresql, multithreading

For example I have query

```
UPDATE foo_table SET viewed_count = coalesce(viewed_count, 0) + 1
```

suppose 100 clients execute this query at same time

Is there any guarantees that **viewed_count** will be incremented by 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

After obtaining the lock on the row, a transaction in `READ COMMITTED` isolation level will re-read the current version of the row.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED):

> `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR SHARE` commands behave the same as `SELECT` in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are negated and the second updater can proceed with updating the originally found row. If the first updater commits, the second updater will ignore the row if the first updater deleted it, otherwise it will attempt to apply its operation to the updated version of the row.